# Change configuration of xml to spring boot

Tags: xml, spring-boot, migration, jackrabbit

I am migrating a project which used **xml** for mapping to **spring boot** **(.java file)**

How should I go about it? Below is the jackrabbit xml configuration...

```
<bean id="repository" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
   <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jcr/myRepository"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jcrSessionFactory" class="org.springmodules.jcr.JcrSessionFactory">
    <property name="repository" ref="repository" />
    <property name="credentials">
      <bean class="javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="admin" />
        <!-- create the credentials using a bean factory -->
        <constructor-arg index="1">
          <bean factory-bean="password" factory-method="toCharArray" />
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

  <!-- create the password to return it as a char[] -->
  <bean id="password" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="admin" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jcrTemplate" class="org.springmodules.jcr.JcrTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="jcrSessionFactory" />
    <property name="allowCreate" value="true" />
  </bean>

<Resource name="jcr/myRepository"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.jcr.Repository"
  factory="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepositoryFactory"
  configFilePath="D:/DMSRepo/repositoryFactlive.xml"
  repHomeDir="D:/DMSRepo/factlivetrialVersion2/repo"/>
```

Comment: Small int `class` references a class... Those things you can create with `new`. Start with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should create a configuration class file using **@Configuration** and import your .xml file using **@ImportResource** like this:-

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:dmsRepository.xml")
public class JackRabbitRepository {

}
```

Then you have to keep your resource content in server.xml file coz it won't work in your current xml. After this your configuration of JackRabbit is done.
Then do what you want to do in DMS.